# Image projections using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I generate a set of image projections using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

I have a 256x256 image. I want to get all 180 projections ranging from 0 degree to 180 degree projection angle.

Is there a way to do that in MATLAB?

Comment: What kind of image projections? Do you have a mathematical definition of the image projection you have in mind? Are you looking for [Radon transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/radon.html) or [Hough transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html)?

Comment: Parallel Beam projections, How they are constructed practically from an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RADON](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/radon.html)

```
theta = 0:180; %# angle from 0 to 180 degrees
R = radon(yourImage,theta);
```

Each column of R corresponds to one angle from the list in theta